# Showing Red Light on Green Surfaces LWJGL

Tags: glsl, lwjgl

Hey everyone I'm working with lighting in a 2D Tile Based game and have run into a problem with my lighting calculations, in my game I take greyscale images then color them using shaders whatever color I like whether that be green(rgb=(0,1,0)) or red(rgb=(1,0,0)) or any color. So then I apply my lighting calculations to that textured and colored pixel. The lighting works fine when the light is white(rgb=(1,1,1)) but when it is say red or green it wont show the way I want it to. I know why this is happening of course because realistic a pure red light in a pure green room would reflect no red light so the room would remain dark. What I really want is to see a red light appear over a green surface. So my question is how can I show a red light clearly on a green surface?(or really any other color on any surface)

This is the code for my fragment shader, where attenuation is simply the attenuation for the light, lightColor is obviously the lights rgb value, distance is the distance from the given vector to that light(calculated in the vertex shader) and finally color is the rgb value that is applied to the texture.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
vec3 totalDiffuse = vec3(0.0);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    float attFactor = attenuation[i].x + (attenuation[i].y * distance[i]) + (attenuation[i].z * distance[i] * distance[i]);
    totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + (lightColor[i])/attFactor;
}
totalDiffuse = max(totalDiffuse,0.2);

out_Color = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords)*vec4(color,alpha)*vec4(totalDiffuse,1);
```

And here is an image of what a pure red light looks like on a surface currently, it should be inside the white circle and you may be able to see it is affecting the water a little bit because I give the water a small red component-
[Light Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL01E.png)

Comment: I understand that and I thought I mentioned that in the post but the issue is With the direction the game is going I won’t know what color the ground is going to be, it’s going to be a completely random color, so I would like the light to show the same red on all surfaces regardless of there color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to change the light calculation.

Calculate a gray scales of the light color and the surface color. Multiply the surface color by the gray scale of the light color and the multiply the light color by the gray scale of the surface color, finally sum them up:

```
vec4  texCol  = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
float grayTex = dot(texCol.rgb,  vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));
float grayCol = dot(colGray.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));

vec3  mixCol  = texCol.rgb * grayCol + color.rgb * grayTex;

out_Color     = vec4(mixCol * totalDiffuse, texCol.a * alpha);
```

Note, this algorithm emphasizes the color of the light at the expense of the color of the surface. But that was what you wanted by dipping a green area in red light. Of course, that contradicts the desire to illuminate an area in its own color. If the light is white, then the surface will also shine white.

If you want some light sources with the effect described above, other sources but with the original effect of the question, then I recommend to introduce a parameter that mixes the two effects:

```
uniform float u_lightTint;

void main()
{
    .....

    vec3 mixCol = texCol.rgb * grayCol + color.rgb * grayTex;

    mixCol      = mix(texCol.rgb * color.rgb, mixCol.rgb, u_lightTint);

    out_Color   = vec4(mixCol * totalDiffuse, texCol.a * alpha); 
}
```

If `u_lightTint` is set 1.0, then the "new" light calculation is uses, it it is set 0.0, then the original light calculation is use. Both algorithms can be interpolated linearly by `u_lightTint`.
Alternatively the `u_lightTint` parameter can be encoded in the alpha channel of the light color:

```
mixCol = mix(texCol.rgb * color.rgb, mixCol.rgb, color.a);
```

Comment: That worked great! Only problem is now white light is overbearingly white, which is what I was afraid of since I use a white light to light up the scene now everything has a lighter hue. But thanks so much!

Comment: Ive been working on this for some time now and still cant seem to get white light to be the way I want it to be, dividing that by 2 doesnt seem to help. Since I light my scene with a white light and now all light colors are exact regardless of the color below everything has this kind of white tint to it when trying to light it. So maybe I need to use my old method of lighting when using white light and any other time use the method you gave me.

Comment: thanks so much again! That seems to work fairly well. You're really helping a lot, the issue now is I have multiple light sources, so if some are green and some are white I would need to use the old lighting calculation for the white light but then somehow combine that with the new lighting calculation for the green light.

Comment: @Setlock See the last sentence of the answer. Encode the "light tint" to the alpha channel of the light color. So each light source has its own tint. e.g.white: RGBA (1, 1, 1, 1) and red RGB (1, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Right but the lighting is calculated by taking all the lightColor values together to make a Total Diffuse, would I then just simply add their respective alpha values to that calculation?

Comment: Actually I think I got it working right! Thanks so much for all your help!